# build error while trying to use octopress in windows 8

Tags: ruby, windows, octopress

I am trying to use octopress in my windows 8 .While i use the command

> bundle install

I am getting the following error .

```
    e:\PROJECTS\octopress>bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/
Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/
Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/
Resolving dependencies...
Using rake 10.5.0
Using RedCloth 4.2.9
Using addressable 2.4.0
Using blankslate 2.1.2.4
Using chunky_png 1.3.6
Installing fast-stemmer 1.0.2 with native extensions

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    C:/Ruby193/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
Invalid argument - C:/Ruby193/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb 2>&1

Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/fast-stem
mer-1.0.2 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/extensions/x86-mingw32/1.9.1/fa
st-stemmer-1.0.2/gem_make.out
Using coffee-script-source 1.10.0
Using execjs 2.7.0
Using colorator 0.1
Using multi_json 1.12.1
Using sass 3.4.22
Using rb-fsevent 0.9.7
Using ffi 1.9.14
Using multipart-post 2.0.0
Using tilt 2.0.5
Using jekyll-paginate 1.1.0
Using kramdown 1.12.0
Using liquid 2.6.3
Using mercenary 0.3.6
Installing posix-spawn 0.3.11 with native extensions

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    C:/Ruby193/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
Invalid argument - C:/Ruby193/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb 2>&1

Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/posix-spa
wn-0.3.11 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/extensions/x86-mingw32/1.9.1/po
six-spawn-0.3.11/gem_make.out
Installing yajl-ruby 1.2.1 with native extensions

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    C:/Ruby193/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
Invalid argument - C:/Ruby193/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb 2>&1

Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/yajl-ruby
-1.2.1 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/extensions/x86-mingw32/1.9.1/ya
jl-ruby-1.2.1/gem_make.out
Installing redcarpet 3.3.4 with native extensions

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    C:/Ruby193/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
Invalid argument - C:/Ruby193/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb 2>&1

Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/redcarpet
-3.3.4 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/extensions/x86-mingw32/1.9.1/re
dcarpet-3.3.4/gem_make.out
Using safe_yaml 1.0.4
Using rack 1.6.4
Installing rdiscount 2.2.0.1 with native extensions

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    C:/Ruby193/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
Invalid argument - C:/Ruby193/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb 2>&1

Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rdiscount
-2.2.0.1 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/extensions/x86-mingw32/1.9.1/rd
iscount-2.2.0.1/gem_make.out
Using stringex 1.4.0
Using bundler 1.12.5
Installing jekyll-sitemap 0.11.0

Errno::EINVAL: Invalid argument - C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jekyll-sit
emap-0.11.0/spec/fixtures/_posts/2016-04-01-i¶↓h
Using parslet 1.5.0
An error occurred while installing fast-stemmer (1.0.2), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install fast-stemmer -v '1.0.2'` succeeds before bundling.
```

How to resolve this error ?. I am using the follwing version of ruby and gem.

- Ruby- 2.2.4
- gem - 2.3.0

Comment: Please add the error message as text. Neither text searches nor assistive technology can make anything of screenshots.

Comment: @IInspectable - I have changed the error message from image to text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying many solution finally I found the way to solve this error .Now I am using octopress in my windows machine.

I have mentioned this issue and solution in my [Personal Blog](https://srabankumar.github.io/blog/2016/09/05/windows-and-octopress-mystery/)